# CTE recursion between parent table and child table

Tags: sql-server, database, recursion

Help! I have a parent table and a child table. These tables serve as references for bill of material structure, using sql server. These two tables contain all BOM data.

I'd like to setup a recursive SQL query where a child is established, then the query recursively checks for all parents. For some reason my query only goes one level deep and stops. I have been unable to determine why. In reading many recursive CTE examples, it is always with a self-referencing table (i.e. one table), but in my example the references loop between two tables.

I added a step column to serve as an indicator for how many recursion levels have been done.

Below is my query, which doesn't work.

```
DECLARE @pn NVarchar(50);
SET @pn = 'fastener';

WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT      STEPS = 1,
                Item.IMA_ItemID AS CID,
                ProductStructure.PST_QtyPerAssy AS QPA, 
                Item_1.IMA_ItemID AS PID 
    FROM        dbo.Item Item 
    INNER JOIN  dbo.ProductStructure ProductStructure
    ON          Item.IMA_RecordID = ProductStructure.PST_IMA_RecordID -- This links the child table to the item table (to get it's p/n)
    INNER JOIN  dbo.ProductStructureHeader ProductStructureHeader -- This links the child table to parent table
    ON          ProductStructureHeader.PSH_RecordID = ProductStructure.PST_PSH_RecordID     
    INNER JOIN  dbo.Item Item_1 -- This links the parent table to the item table (to get it's p/n)
    ON          Item_1.IMA_RecordID = ProductStructureHeader.PSH_IMA_RecordID
    WHERE       Item.IMA_ItemID=@pn --Establishes seed p/n (fastener)
            AND Item_1.IMA_DefaultRev=1 --Only shows parent's which are default

    UNION   ALL

    SELECT      CTE.STEPS + 1, --Denotes recursion level +1
                xItem.IMA_ItemID AS CID,
                xProductStructure.PST_QtyPerAssy AS QPA, 
                xItem_1.IMA_ItemID AS PID 
    FROM        dbo.Item xItem 
    INNER JOIN  dbo.ProductStructure xProductStructure
    ON          xItem.IMA_RecordID = xProductStructure.PST_IMA_RecordID -- Links child to item table to get part number
    INNER JOIN  dbo.ProductStructureHeader xProductStructureHeader
    ON          xProductStructureHeader.PSH_RecordID = xProductStructure.PST_PSH_RecordID       -- Links child table to parent table
    INNER JOIN  dbo.Item xItem_1
    ON          xItem_1.IMA_RecordID = xProductStructureHeader.PSH_IMA_RecordID --Links parent table to item table to get part number

    INNER JOIN  CTE 
    ON          PID = CTE.CID --Links child search results to parent on previous search
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

Comment: What is wrong with the results of  your query?   Do you get an error?   Do you mistakenly believe that the WHERE clause in your top query is going to filter all those Cartesian joins in the bottom query?

Comment: You really should start using the ANSI-92 style joins instead of the older and more error prone style joins you have here. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins Your problem explanation is only "this doesn't work". That doesn't explain what the problem is at all.

Comment: I am 99% certain the issue here is that you have no where clause in the second query so you are getting a cross join between all those tables which isn't what you want.

Comment: @TabAlleman The query results return just one level deep results. No error message. I need it go multiple levels.

Comment: Why are you selecting from `Item` twice in each query?

Comment: The parent and child tables reference an IMA_RecordID GUID. By linking the item table, I can then reference a more appetizing Item part number instead. I cannot link the item part number on one table to both the child and parent table. I'm not sure if there is a better way to do this, but the above method does work.

Comment: @Sean Thanks for the article link. I have editted my query to use ANSI-92 style. I still have issues with my query. It only returns one level 1 results. It should go multiple levels (as i know the item I am searching has multiple levels).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, last `PID = CTE.CID` is equal to `CTE.PID = CTE.CID` because you don't have `PID` column in any of joined tables - it's an alias and you can't use it in the same query in joins or wherever else.

Comment: @Ivan Thanks Ivan, I suspected this was the area not working correctly. I keep tweaking the code and magically got it working.   CTE.PID = xItem.IMA_ItemID